# Deploying Django to Heroku (Psycopg2 Error)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, deployment, heroku

So I'm following the getting started guide from heroku with django. However when I run this command:

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

I get this error

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I assumed this meant that the db wasn't set up yet... so I manually added the shared_db option as well:

```
heroku addons:add shared-database:5mb
```

But.. I still get the same error. What gives?

Comment: Could you try with a simple script doing a manual connection if it is a general problem or specific to Django.

Comment: Having the same problem, did you fix it in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app structure was off... heroku wants the structure to look like this:

```
toplevel
  requirements.txt
  myapp
    manage.py
    all other django stuff
```

Answer (score 8):

**EDITED:**

As @mipadi has pointed out here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001031/django-heroku-settings-injection/13092534), it can actually be as simple as this:

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {'default' : dj_database_url.config() }
```

This works if you have a DATABASE_URL env variable set. heroku:pg_promote gets your there. Details below

---

Make sure you have Postgres on your Heroku

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev
```

Step 1: figure out your database url

```
heroku config | grep POSTGRESQL
```

The output will look something like this:

> HEROKU_POSTGRESQL__URL:
>   postgres://user:password@host:5432/blabla

Step 2: Grab the setting name from the previous step (e.g. HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE_URL) and put it in your settings file like so

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ["HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE_URL"])}
```

[UPDATE] As Ted has pointed out, there's a way to promote the color URL to DATABASE_URL variable:

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE_URL
```

Your database settings can then use DATABASE_URL as opposed to more exotic colored URLS

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])}
```

Bob is your uncle

Comment: For those still struggling with Heroku + Django, I've put together a boilerplate to get going fast. Very opinionated but it gets stuff done: https://github.com/callmephilip/django-heroku-bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by adding the following code to settings.py myself, seems for some reason Heroku didn't add it for me....

Normally it always added the code on Heroku dynamically but I guess after django 1.4 it didnt do it anymore for some reason. Or I was just doing something wrong.

Anyway this is the code just append it to your settings.py and it should work as before.

```
import sys
import urlparse
import os


# Register database schemes in URLs.
urlparse.uses_netloc.append('postgres')
urlparse.uses_netloc.append('mysql')

try:

    # Check to make sure DATABASES is set in settings.py file.
    # If not default to {}

    if 'DATABASES' not in locals():
        DATABASES = {}

    if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
        url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])

        # Ensure default database exists.
        DATABASES['default'] = DATABASES.get('default', {})

        # Update with environment configuration.
        DATABASES['default'].update({
            'NAME': url.path[1:],
            'USER': url.username,
            'PASSWORD': url.password,
            'HOST': url.hostname,
            'PORT': url.port,
        })
        if url.scheme == 'postgres':
            DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'

        if url.scheme == 'mysql':
            DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.mysql'
except Exception:
    print 'Unexpected error:', sys.exc_info()
```

Comment: I am running django 1.3.1 still... upvoting for possible 1.4 solution :)

Comment: Did you try it? It may work for 1.3 also, it may be related to using the Shared DB isntead of Dev DB, but cant verify that. I think this may fix your problem also.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this is how I solved it

Step1: Follow Phillip's Step 1 to get database name(color)

Step2:

```
$ heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOR>
```

leads to the output

```
Promoting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOR> to DATABASE_URL... done
```

Comment: Very nice, Ted. I'll incorporate this bit in my original answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your requirements.txt:

```
psycopg2
```

By default Heroku configures a Postgres database and injects code into your settings.py (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#postgres_database_config). This reads from the environment variable DATABASE_URL, but does require psycopg2 is installed.

Comment: That exists in my requirements.txt file, been following these setup instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django