# Django/Heroku Settings injection?

Tags: django, deployment, heroku, settings

I want to be able to change my DATABASES['default'] setting to change automatically when I deploy to heroku.  Is there some way to do this?

This looks like what I want
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-injection, but it seems like it no longer works as of July 1, 2012.

Comment: Got here looking for what `.heroku/injection_disabled` does? It used to disable injection into settings.py but is no longer necessary. See https://web.archive.org/web/20130925020700/https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-injection

Answer (score 1):

Use `dj_database_url`, as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#database-settings). To wit:

```
$ pip install dj-database-url
```

and then in `settings.py`:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

You can pass `config` a `default` argument if you don't want to set `DATABASE_URL` locally. More info is available [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url).

Comment: I believe it's safer to do the following: DATABASES = {'default' : dj_database_url.config() }